# Previous and next entries nav – within a categeory

Tags: category

I'm not sure what I've done, I had this working at the top of my entry.html template:

---

```
{% set params = craft.entries.section('ourWork').relatedTo(category) %}

{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}

{% if prevEntry %}<a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">Previous</a>{% endif %}
{% if nextEntry %}<a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">Next</a>{% endif %}
```

For some reason I just get:
Variable "category" does not exist

The section name is correct and this does have a category field assigned.

my index template category part is:

```
{# Projects
---------------------------------------------------------------------------#}
<div class="banner projects">
<div class="row">        
  <ul class="no-bullet small-up-2 medium-up-3 large-up-4 large-centered"> 
  {#
  Display catgeory nav 'ourWork'
  #}
    {% nav category in craft.categories.group('ourWork').level(1) %}         
      <li class= "column">                        
          {# <p>{{ category.WorkCategoryDescription }}<p> #}                 
          <a href="{{ category.url }}"><img src="{{ category.categoryImageThumb.first.getUrl('categoryThumbnail') }}"></a>             
          <p> <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }} </a><p>
      </li>
    {% endnav %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how you use these two snippets of code together?

Answer (score 1):

When you are within your `nav` tag context, `category` definitely exists, even if you're using `include` for the first snippet you posted. If you're talking about the automatically pre-assigned variable for a single category's page, make sure the category group settings are still correct and that you are requesting the right URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing: `{% set category = entry.workCategory%}`